# while loop using raw data

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create code using a while loop which will stop the user from inputting an invalid date when inputting raw data:

```
while True:
    try:
        Date = int(raw_input("Please input the Date in the format DDMM:"))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter a valid date in the format DDMM")
        continue
    if int(Date[0]) > 3 or Date < 0 or int(Date[2]) > 1:
        print ("Please enter a valid date in the format DDMM")
        continue
    if int(Date[2:4]) > 12:
        print ("Please enter a valid date in the format DDMM")
        continue
    if int(Date[2:4])==1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12 and int(Date[0:2])>31:
        print ("Please enter a valid date in the format DDMM")
        continue
    if int(Date[2:4])==2 and int(Date[0:2])>28:
        print ("Please enter a valid date in the format DDMM")
        continue
    if int(Date[2:4])==4 or 6 or 9 or 11 and int(Date[0:2])>30:
        print ("Please enter a valid date in the format DDMM")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

I am getting the following error message when I run the code

> ```
> if int(Date[0]) > 3 or Date < 0 or int(Date[2]) > 1:
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Apparently, ints don't have a `__getitem__` method. What now?

Comment: The `getitem` error stems from the fact that an integer has no subscript `[]` operator to access digits, while a string does. Try to remove the wrapping `int(...)` around `raw_input(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you get input from the user you're casting it as an Integer immediately, but then in your conditions you're trying to index or take a slice of an integer which isn't going to work

So to fix your immediate problem, change your line:

```
Date = int(raw_input("Please input the Date in the format DDMM:"))
```

to

```
Date = raw_input("Please input the Date in the format DDMM:")
```

There are some other problems with your code that will prevent it from working as desired though. For example, this is incorrect syntactically:

```
if int(Date[2:4])==4 or 6 or 9 or 11 and int(Date[0:2])>30
```

At the very least, as a direct fix, you'd need to do something like:

```
if int(Date[2:4])==4 or int(Date[2:4])==6 or int(Date[2:4])==9 or int(Date[2:4])==11 and int(Date[0:2])>30
```

However you might want to think about refactoring your code to make things a bit cleaner overall

Comment: That won't work with thw rest of his/her code either.

Comment: My bad, didnt see the int() calls around the slices

Answer (score 1):

You are making Date an int

```
Date = int(raw_input("Please input the Date in the format DDMM:"))
```

and the you accessing it via `[]` which calls `__getitem__`.

For that to work you need to convert it back to a string.

```
Date = str( Date )
```

Either way, there is inconsistent usage of Date, for example

```
Date < 0
```

treats it as number.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

def validate(d):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m%d')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Please enter a valid date in the format MMDD")

validate('1010')
validate('1099')
```